# Recursive mySQL Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, percona

I have a problem that I need to use a recursive statement to solve. My issue is that when I try to use the WITH statement I get an error (unrecognized statement near WITH).

We are running the following service

**Server type:** Percona Server

**Server version:** 5.6.41-84.1 - Percona Server (GPL), Release 84.1, Revision b308619

I am not sure if it's just the case that recursive statements are not supported on this version and we need to upgrade or if it's something else.

Comment: The WITH clause is not supported by your MySql version.

Comment: damn it, so no way I can create a recursive statement, I have to do this on the front. Thanks

Comment: *I have to do this on the front* You may create iterative stored procedure. Moreover, this will be more fast then client-side data processing.